# How to capitalise and change last special character in a string stored in the variable?

Tags: regex

How can I convert this string `hello,how,are,you` to `Hello,How,Are & You`.

The text is contained in a variable. I would like to solve it by using regex. I have to use this in tasker.

Comment: What language/tool are you using?

Comment: Hi there, please read [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) so we can best help you

Comment: @Tim, I have a tasker variable which contains the lowercase words separated by comma's and I am going to use this in tasker app

Answer (score 0):

I'm unclear of your question, however with the assumption this could be in Python, there is an function `.title()` you can use with strings.

e.g.

```
stringVar = "hello,world"
stringVar.title()
```

output:

```
"Hello,World"
```

Comment: Hi @T.Pilvelis thanks for the reply, I am new to this forum thing so please bear with me